# sizeof() on arrays on stack vs. on heap

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, sizeof, stack-memory

I'm learning C++ and I’ve noticed that the `sizeof()`-operator works differently on arrays on the stack and on the heap. For instance:

```
int onStack[5];
int* onHeap = new int[5];
std::cout << "sizeof(onStack)=" << sizeof(onStack) << std::endl;
std::cout << "sizeof(onHeap)=" << sizeof(onHeap) << std::endl;
```

generates the output

```
sizeof(onStack)=20
sizeof(onHeap)=4
```

However, as far as I can tell, both `onStack` and `onHeap` are just `int` pointers, right? I’m aware that you shouldn’t / can’t really use the `sizeof()`-operator to get the size of an array, but just out of curiosity, why does it behave differently, depending on whether the array is on the stack or on the heap?

Comment: I believe you are mistaken as to what `sizeof` does.

Comment: Meh, The duplicate I picked wasn't all that good, and I couldn't find another, so I'm reopening. I still think this was probably answered *well* in some way, shape or form before. But I can't find it.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, probably tons of dups, if you find one, happy to remove my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `onStack` is a `int[5]` wich decays to a pointer. They are not the same, hence the `sizeof` difference.

Nothing to do with on stack vs on heap, it's really just type difference.

Comment: Wow, that was quick :D thanks, that makes sense! I just looked up array decaying and found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying, which further clarifies this concept.

Comment: @Macklin • The `onHeap` pointer is not an example of pointer decay.  It is an example of being a pointer to a heap allocated array.  In modern C++, probably better to use `std::vector`.